# Phonegap (Cordova) - File not found Exception in reading file from FileSystem

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, filesystems

In order to send one file from my android device's File System to one server, I am using cordova 3.5 and the following code (as you can get reading this code the file is inside my Download directory):

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess, fail);

}
function fsSuccess(fs){
    fs.root.getDirectory("Download", {create: false, exclusive: false}, doDirectoryListing, FileError);
}

function doDirectoryListing(dirEntry) {     
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(gotFiles, FileError);
}

function gotFiles(entries)
{   
    var wsUrl = "http://myServer/";
    var fileToSend =  "file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/"+entries[0].name, "file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/";
    multipart.uploadFiles(success, error,  wsUrl, fileToSend);  
}
```

I can read all the files (names) that are in /Download parsing all the **entries** but I dont know how to get a specific file (for instance entries[0])  which needs to be passed to **uploadFiles** function.

**Problem:** I tried in different manner as for instance concatenating it with **"file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/"** but always getting a *file not found exception*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own,

mainly **file://** is to be removed.

It could be gained this way: `fileToSend.replace("file://", ""));`